# How to maintain the loaded bitmap image while moving the mfc dialog outside the screen in c++?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-c++, mfc

I have loaded an bitmap image to a static control in MFC using StrechBlt().But when I moved the dialog outside the windows screen, a part of the image is erased.Anyone know why it is happening?

Below is the code to load bitmap image to static control:

```
bool LoadImage(CString path)
{
        HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, path, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
        CBitmap bitmap;
        CDC cdc;
        CClientDC DC(GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC));
        CStatic* pStaticText = (CStatic*)GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC);    
        bitmap.Attach((HBITMAP)hBitmap);
        cdc.CreateCompatibleDC(&DC))        
        CBitmap* pBM = cdc.SelectObject(&bitmap);
        BITMAP bitmapObj;
        bitmap.GetBitmap(&bitmapObj);
        CRect rect;
        CWnd *pWnd = GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC_IMAGE_CAPTURE_AREA);
        pWnd->GetWindowRect(&rect);
        ScreenToClient(&rect);
        DC.StretchBlt(0, 0, rect.Width(), rect.Height(), &cdc, 0, 0, bitmapObj.bmWidth, bitmapObj.bmHeight, SRCCOPY);
        cdc.SelectObject(pBM);
        pStaticText->SetBitmap((HBITMAP)bmp);
        cdc.DeleteDC();
        bitmap.DeleteObject(); 
        return true;
}
```

Comment: You haven't actually loaded in the bitmap into the control, you've just drawn on the control, your drawing will be lost when the control repaints (I think, I've not used MFC)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cstatic-class?view=vs-2019 might help

Comment: [CStatic::SetBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cstatic-class#setbitmap).

Comment: Though I am confused what `Public` and `Bool` are. Or why `LoadImage` doesn't return a value. Generic advice: Learn to crawl before you attempt to run. Get the bases covered first, and read how [painting and drawing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/painting-and-drawing) works in the Windows API. Attempting to use MFC without knowing the Windows API has not ever been a successful endeavor.

Comment: @AlanBirtles  : It doesn't work for me

Comment: @IInspectable : Sorry my mistake

Comment: `public bool LoadImage(CString path)` isn't valid C++. What programming language are you using?

Comment: @IInspectable Changed.Please check.

Comment: Still, odd. Why does `LoadImage` return a value at all, when all it ever returns is `true`? Anyway, that's not the issue here, though I'm still confused, how .NET relates to any of this.

Comment: Your `LoadImage()` function contains code that both loads the image and paints it, which is not ideal. The point is where you call it from. You may not paint, unless while processing of a `WM_PAINT` message (`CWnd::OnDraw()`). Also, you should best not be performing "lengthy" operations while painting (eg loading the image), for performance reasons. So, I would recomment two possible implementations: A) Load the image (and keep it loaded for as long as needed) and paint it when requested (`WM_PAINT`/`OnDraw()`) and B) Use the SetBitmap() function (`SS_BITMAP`-style static controls).